# How to run a Javascript program from sublime text edit 2 to a web browser?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and am having trouble trying to open my Javascipt program to a web browser for testing. How is this done through Sublime Text Edit? I don't see any option for running to a browser. I can go to build then run but it all complies at the bottom of the screen. So how is it run directly to chrome?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Browsers load HTML pages. In HTML page you have an option to load and execute JavaScript code via `<script>` tag.

1. Create a HTML page
2. Put it to the same folder with your .JS file
3. In HTML have a `<script>` tag that loads your code:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="myjsfile.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Open this HTML file in Chrome (drag and drop, double click, etc.)

(Note: Nowadays there are also command line JavaScript programs which are run with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), but they are not usually for programming novices).